# replace_if in string to replace

Tags: c++, string, c++11, lambda

I was solving one simple problem with the use of replace_if but every time it gives me error.
**Problem**:
in a given string remove the adjacent character and make string as compact as possible.
**Ex:** aabcc will become b and aabbcc will become empty string.

```
int main()
{
    string s;
    cin>>s;    
    replace_if(s.begin(),s.end(),[](char l, char r){return l == r;},"");
    cout << string(s.begin(),s.end());   
    return 0;
}
```

**Error:**

```
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algo.h:4280:12: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided  
solution.cc:19:51: note: candidate:  
main()::<lambda(char, char)> 
replace_if(s.begin(),s.end(),[](char l, char r){
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Have you read any [documentation of `replace_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace)?

Comment: Yes read the documentation but not able to understand..

Comment: @InvI `std::replace_if` can't change the size of the string, it can only change elements from one value to another. Look for another method.

Comment: It would be helpful for everyone if you followed the guidelines here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Blastfurnace Thanks now i know why this function is not working.

Comment: Why would you try to use algo with `replace` in its name to remove elements?

Comment: @Slava i got confuse to replace element with blank.but now clear..Thanks

Comment: That you've read the documentation but didn't understand it should be mentioned in your question, ideally spcifying what exactly you didn't understand (if you're able to tell).

Comment: Unrelated to the problem at hand, but you might be interested in our list of [good C++ books](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465).

Comment: @Angew Thanks for list of book...i will refer.

Comment: I do not think `std::remove_if` is easy solvable for your task, it is possible but overhead would be bigger than writing loop

Answer (score 4):

`std::replace_if` operates on a sequence of values of a certain type (in your case, of type `char`), and can be used to examine each value in the sequence and potentially replace it with another value of the same type. In other words, if allows you to replace all `a`s with `b`s, but doesn't allow removing elements or basing the predicate on more than the inspected element itself.

What you need is a bit more complicated to compose, but could be done e.g. like this:

```
auto it = s.begin();
for (;;)
{
  it = std::adjacent_find(it, s.end()); // Find two adjacent same characters
  if (it == s.end()) // If there are none, we're done
    break;
  auto next = std::find_if(it, s.end(), [it](char c) { return c != *it; }); // Find next different character
  it = s.erase(it, next); // Erase all in range [it, next)
}
```

Comment: I think just loop without algos would be simpler, more readable and efficient

Comment: @Slava I disagree, since keeping track of adjacent indices/iterators is prone to off-by-one errors. And as far as efficiency goes, I'd assume it to be identical: it's all just one iteration, after all.